# How to dynamically add elements to a Dojo ComboBox

Tags: dojo

I have a  Dojo combobox declaratively created using a standard HTML select.  There is an onChange event on a separate textbox that invokes a function to get data from a server via XHR and elements of the response data become new options for the drop down.

I've been trying examples across the internet but nothing so far has worked.  This is the code I'm currently trying with no errors.  In fact, when I look at the contents of the store after the put, the data is in there.

When I click on the drop down after the data has been set, I get the error "_AutoCompleterMixin.js.uncompressed.js:557 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined":

```
var newOptions = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    newOptions[i] = { value: jsonData[i].dataID, 
                      label: jsonData[i].dataName, 
                      selected: i == 0};
}

var select = registry.byId("combobox");
select.store.put(newOptions, { overwrite: true });
```

And also "select.store.data = newOptions;".
And also moving the code around so "select.store.add(option)" is within the loop.

Though the combobox store is being populated in all three cases, I continue get the same error.  There are no null values in the data.  There are no blank values in the data.

What am I missing?  No example anywhere, within the DOJO docs or anywhere else has this problem, even working jsFiddle examples.

I simply cannot see what the difference is other than the fact I'm adding more than one or two hard-coded values.

Answer (score 0):

It takes:

```
newOptions[i] = { id: jsonData[i].dataID, 
                      name: jsonData[i].dataName, 
                      selected: i == 0};
```

not

```
newOptions[i] = { value: jsonData[i].dataID, 
                      label: jsonData[i].dataName, 
                      selected: i == 0};
```